Did Jamal Husseini say "The blood will flow like rivers in the Middle East"?
On page 50 of his 2008 book 1948: A History of the First Arab–Israeli War, Benny Morris wrote:

The Arab reaction was just as predictable: “The blood will flow like rivers in the Middle East,” promised Jamal Husseini.

There is a very similar quote by Heykal Pasha:

At the 29th Meeting of the UN Ad Hoc Committee on Palestine on 24 November 1947, Dr Heykal Pasha, the Egyptian delegate, said, "If the united Nations decides to amputate a part of Palestine in order to establish a Jewish state, no force on earth could prevent blood from flowing there...However....once such bloodshed has commenced, no force on earth can confine it to the borders of Palestine itself. If Arab blood shed in Palestine, Jewish blood will necessarily be shed elsewhere in the Arab World despite all sincere efforts of the Governments concerned to prevent such reprisals. To place in certain and serious danger a million Jews simply in order to save a hundred thousand in Europe or to satisfy the Zionist dream?
" source

Did the late Palestinian politician Jamal Al Husseini say that and what is the full quote?

In the relevant paragraph from the book there is a reference to footnote 61. It is not clear whether the footnoote only pertains to the immediately preceding sentence or also pertains to the statement quoted in the question. Have you followed up on that footnote? What, if anything did you find?

An article in New York Times of September 30, 1947 declared:
PALESTINIAN ARABS REJECT U.N. PLANS; WARN OF A BATTLE; Jamal el-Husseini Threatens to Drench Holy Land With Blood 'in Lawful Defense'

It is not clear what was the direct quote, and to what extent this is an exaggeration by NYT.
Azzam Pasha's quote
A related quote is that by the secretary of the Arab League Abdul Rahman Hassan Azzam: This will be a war of extermination and a momentous massacre  The quote apparently appears in an interview:

An October 11, 1947 report on the pan-Arab summit in the Lebanese town of Aley,[9] by Akhbar al-Yom's editor Mustafa Amin, contained an interview he held with Arab League secretary-general Azzam. Titled, "A War of Extermination," the interview read as follows (translated by Efraim Karsh; all ellipses are in the original text):

Abdul Rahman Azzam Pasha spoke to me about the horrific war that was in the offing… saying:
"I personally wish that the Jews do not drive us to this war, as this will be a war of extermination and momentous massacre which will be spoken of like the Tartar massacre[10] or the Crusader wars. I believe that the number of volunteers from outside Palestine will be larger than Palestine's Arab population, for I know that volunteers will be arriving to us from [as far as] India, Afghanistan, and China to win the honor of martyrdom for the sake of Palestine … You might be surprised to learn that hundreds of Englishmen expressed their wish to volunteer in the Arab armies to fight the Jews.


The original Arabic text is provided under the link given above.
Remark
It is worth noting that the disbelief about this statement is likely more motivated by modern sensibilities than its improbability - indeed, today a politician saying something like this would be accused of calling for violence and genocide. Instead they prefer to couch it in euphemisms like resistance, revolution, armed struggle, etc. (One could add war on terror, counter-terrorism, self-defense as terms that are equally abused, although I would caution against drawing moral equivalence between these two sets.)
However, 1947 was just a few years after World War II - the greatest slaughter in human history, and the attitudes about mass murder could be quite callous. Moreover, as Benny Morris discusses with multiple examples, in the run-up to Arab-Israeli 1948 war, the attacks against innocent civilians were quite common and considered as justified by both sides in the conflict.

Thank you for your answer. "with the last drop of our blood" makes a huge difference in meaning though.  At first, I couldn't use this account so I posted as a visitor. I can't accept your answer but I upvoted. If you want to post the answer in skeptics: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56865/did-jamal-husseini-say-the-blood-will-flow-like-rivers-in-the-middle-east I'll accept it too.
